# Errors using class defined in another module in python project

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a project with the following hierarchy and I am trying to use a class defined in the file `Student.py` in the file `webcam_classifier.py`. I do so like this:

```
from .Student import Student
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.Student'; '__main__' is not a package
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated!!!

[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of  `.` in `.Student`?

Comment: @CristiFati I was attempting to access the directory a level up from the current folder but it is probably a mistake. I'm not really sure as to what the right way of going about this is

Comment: Then you might want to add another one :) https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

Comment: @CristiFati When I do so, I get the following error: `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Comment: Then what about `from Models.Student`?

Comment: @CristiFati I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Models'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)